# Set SameSite = none on Azure login URI while performing SSO

Tags: spring-boot, azure, cookies, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I have a spring boot application which uses Azure AD SSO for authentication. In the application we have set samesite = none.

This header is set on all the URIs except for login.

```
login/oauth2/code/azure?code=0.AQwAAq5v9jZdW0m_4Him_5-ObgZ6XJdU9odEvIl7FMgAWRMMAAc.AQABAAIAAAD--DLA3VO7QrddgJg7Wevrf_LxXYQSDTyoXoG0oa7zsgo8LLnATNGZy5mPBjV9RzbVvCio8r_NzBpj-D1-TBWwLGrXZSb7rA142-6NaJ4Dh0aD4KR94dNSxiX4zRfwWP5ohL6wJbaE5VmI0nuiuBeuDnrZEkz_aOGl55PQmIi8bxqZciPPxFXuTx5FXJEyybRjX8KlgWPQEDIF-9h_lnoojKy1LowZQ1eKvt05BHtsO9064B491cddNxZ4kxPSXhuNR56qlft4k98dDWmgnbJUwcFA8yFh20yf4kKUfXYlJ4PlTpsHvLDl86duaP74VDHCLjfvPRYJpCZaYSe94a23FLilsJA1_F0YnfYroHMrjG10FuVKqYUtv3xyI6cVl92ttwh8rT-Cdjn142gcfS-fwkfbjXCqXs_itjz_WbHYohU6hx_dO5hIxN2DsalN-Iv_JkG3777x9WnladfwyP_8WRopr4x-8zdvfMJVQWlLhy1RFw2o529sg0q1mUmYLerHiLw80_GMU2CALszVjZU5g9IkKK_tvw0elqkDBBUdY4dXdLUjUX507TqB77f5XDKAU3qnz0nDF_6sbAa3-QQyM3wHc_4R7lnmF_MWNMO4xtBistEkc0OlpL3x2kmrZMnk-nePN3SE6Zy6em6_IWSTUhOyeCoEtF-3LQjQG10k3Er49VQmP8uNrhozZPYwG_X16GA7o9EEZHGdMq47tzxZlBvUbaWZgjl-lU6qThwPYLSarGqoEsowOtJTFSGqXuggAA&state=J9x07243AGxYQgzczpapMIrnN23nHspp2Pu0Ec-ISPM%3d&session_state=7e2e0287-c080-4b8c-bdaa-26918c41fdf7
```

I have looking for information around it on how to set the cookie header on this URI, but couldn't find much

[image]

Answer (score 0):

OAuth flows won't work unless you already have a cookie from the request that redirected you to Azure.

When you've loaded the page that has your "Sign in with Microsoft" button which will look something like:

```
<a href="/oauth2/authorization/azure">
    <img alt="Sign in with Microsoft" src="/img/sign-in-with-microsoft.svg">
</a>
```

Prior to clicking that button you should find you have a cookie with SameSite=None

[Application Cookies showing JSESSIONID cookie with SameSite=None](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PqeW.png)

Then, when you "Sign in with Microsoft", the redirect back to your server will use that cookie when hitting `login/oauth2/code/azure`